# Error while compiling / debugging VB 2008 source code

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I am working on a VB programm in Visual Studio 2008.
It worked fine, but from one day to another I got below error message.
I can not manage to get rid of it. Is there anyone who can help.
At this point my program cannot be build or compiled nor tested.

```
Unable to read manifest 'My Project\app.manifest'. Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlXml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.
```

The manifest file is in the correct place. I did download `system.data.sqlxml` and placed in also in the `bin`. but no result.  I do not know what i did that made this error. It just was there at once. before all worked fine.

Please help !
Thanks

Comment: It seems the system.data.sqlxml 2.0.0.0 is needed. I did install the 10.0.0.0 version. Is there a way to downgrade or replace ?

Comment: Have you added system.data.sqlxml as a reference AND written "Imports System.Data.SqlXml"?